# Drupal -> User error: Failed to connect to memcache server

Tags: caching

I had someone install memcache for one Drupal project. Apparently we moved to another hosting. Upon completing the migration, the site is having issues with memcache.

Can someone guide me on how to remove the error? Please see below. I believe this is the right section for the topic, but if you find it inappropriate for this category, please feel free to move it. Thank you.

```
User error: Failed to connect to memcache server: 127.0.0.1:11211 in dmemcache_object() (line 415 of/home/searchpa/public_html/sites/all/modules/memcache/dmemcache.inc).
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to check how mem cached was run on your hosts. You can check this like so:

```
ps -Af | grep memcached
```

Check if it has -l 127.0.0.1 in arguments. If it is the case then just restart memcached with correct IP address instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This is what I get: `ps -Af | grep memcached
root 9077 5701 0 11:46 pts/0 00:00:00 grep memcached`. It doesn't seem it has "-l 127.0.0.1" in the argument. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: it rather means that memcached on your server is not running at all. You should install and run it.